# No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql

Tags: spring, jdbc, gradle

I'm new to Spring/Gradle and am trying to create a web Api that connects to a PostgreSQL database.

This is where I attempt to establish the `Connection`:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class PostgreSQLJDBC {

    public static void connect() {
        System.out.println("Started connection attempt");
        Connection c = null;
        try {
            c = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb",
                            "root", "password");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName()+": "+e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
    }
}
```

Here is my `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.1.RELEASE")
        classpath("org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1207")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-rest-service'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1207")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

The `Exception` is this:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb

I have looked at the other questions with similar problems and some of them were solved by using adding `Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");` just before attempting the connection. This did not work for me either, resulting in:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver

Besides, other questions said not to put the `Class.forName` for JDBC4.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

PostgreSQL just does not show up in the classpath...

[image]

Comment: If you use an IDE such as IntelliJ, are you able to find the class `org.postgresql.Driver` in your classpath?

Comment: Just checked. Somehow it's not in there. I'm using IntelliJ.

Comment: Try to remove the postgresql dependency from your `buildscript`, it should only be needed as a module dependency. Once you're able to pull the driver in correctly, the error should go away.

Comment: It didn't work. It's still not in the classpath. Exact same errors.

Comment: Is that project hosted online?

Comment: No it's local. I will eventually be hosting it on a linux machine at my school though.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample app that reproduces the problem?

Comment: It's seems that it works. Any particular steps should I take to reproduce the problem? Also, running spring boot app on port 80 isn't the best idea.

Comment: Try loading `http://localhost/api/account/register` which is hardcoded to call `connect()`. Why isn't port 80 a good idea? I was planning on it being a simple web api.

Comment: It works correctly, I've received a JSON response. Since 80 is a port for web applications/sites. Typically you run spring on 8080 and use some kind of proxy nginx/apache that works on 80 and proxies the requests. Also for security reasons.

Comment: Ok. This is weird. It doesn't work on mine. Do you have Postgres 9.5? Also, maybe it works for you because you have the jar added to the dependencies manually (like in the github repo - build.gradle). Do you think you can get it to work without using the jar manually?

Comment: Just added an image of my libraries in the post. Also, I forgot to tell you but the issue is on the jdbc branch, not master, so that may be why it worked for you.

Comment: Ports below 1024 require root privileges on Linux machines; for this reason port 8080 is preferred.

Comment: That is the Java 8 version of the driver, are you running Java 8?

Comment: Yes I am. Together with psql 9.5 but I've also tried 9.4 and come across the same thing.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the Postgresql version, it can't find the driver, so it can't connect, as the driver is on the maven central repository, it looks like some sort of caching problem. Have you tried refreshing (reimporting) your gradle project?

Comment: Just figured it out! It turns out that IntelliJ 14.1.5 I was using was buggy in some way. Reimporting didn't do anything. But I installed IntelliJ 15 and everything works now! Thanks!